# three.js - Export multiple separated object with geometry and materials separately to json

Tags: three.js

I'm newby with three.js.
I know there's a JSONLoader to load JSON from a file/url. 
But is it possible to export  models(objects, meshes) with their geometries and matirial separately to json and then pass it to server for save it to database?

I think, I'll need select mesh by id or name, and export it to json, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core `Object3D` class has a `toJSON()` method that returns the data as js object without cyclic references. You just need to stringify it, maybe. The output should be readable again by the JSONLoader.

```
var json = JSON.stringify(myObj.toJSON());
```

If you just want the geometry or material data, you can call this method from those instances. And if you want to export the whole scene, you can call `scene.toJSON()`.